# How to convert array to object return const type like this?

Tags: typescript

Maybe need to get the type of argument, but I don't know what to do

```js
function converArrayToObject(keys) {
    return keys.reduce((prev, key) => ({ ...prev, [key]: key}), {})
}

const result = converArrayToObject(['aa', 'bb']);
// expected result type : `{ aa: string, bb: string }`
```

Comment: Does [this approach](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABBBA3ApgJwIKcwQwE8AVOAeQCMArdaAHhTAGcpFjF0APKdMAEyaJM6fHwQAbQohaYYYAOYBtALoA+ABQBrdISYAuNgEpEAbwBQiIeighMSbboB0wviAjp16gA7DUAGkQHYwBeVUR1E0RHaJ90f0RFB2UDB0QAX0MAkzTEfEEAJVo4TD46YkUwEABbCixlAJk5eVVDAG4zNLMzAHpuy0KUEroAInx8YcQAH0RhigphhqhZBVUzRhYrJhBxVmDkNCxcAhJyaloodUUAcjGrgKu5q+U2syA) work for you? If yes, I'll write an answer explaining; If not, what am I missing?

Comment: That is not what you use reduce for. Just do foreach returning "{value: typeof value,...}";

Comment: @digitalniweb why not? Code transforms array to an object

Comment: @wonderflame that you can do something doesn't mean you should. Does he need accumulator (previous values)? You can use hammer to get inside a car but you shouldn't if you have keys. It's harder to read and use the code when you can simply use a oneliner.

Comment: @digitalniweb how you are going to do that with forEach? You will need to have a separate constant outside of the forEach in which you are going to put the keys, which is basically accumulating

Comment: @wonderflame on second look you are right. It's ok to use reduce here I guess.

Comment: uh, I'm not sure whether Record<'aa'|'bb', string> is equal to { aa: string, bb: string } @wonderflame

Comment: @wonderflame difference is that you don't incur the heavy memory allocation due to all the new objects being allocated and copied over. Which itself can incur a GC cost of having to clean up. Although with a `reduce` you can also avoid the many copies with `.reduce((prev, key) => (prev[key] = key, prev), {})`

Comment: @flyflydogdog it is equal

Comment: @digitalniweb `Record` is calling a mapped type in itself. They are identical. See [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABBBA3ApgJwIKcwQwE8AVOAeQCMArdaAHhTAGcpFjF0APKdMAEyaJM6fHwQAbQohaYYYAOYBtALoA+ABQBrdISYAuNgEpEAbwBQiIeighMSbboB0wviAjp16gA7DUAGkQHYwBeVUR1E0RHaJ90f0RFB2UDB0QAX0MAkzTEfEETRQBpRDk2RTAQAFsKLGVk6ShZBQyAbjM0szNGFismEHFWYOQ0LFwCEnJqWih1RQByfHw5gLmKCjnlQzagA)

Comment: It seems correct. @wonderflame

Comment: @wonderflame I would love to see an answer using the `Record` type and and the difference to the mapped type approach :D

Comment: @Behemoth there is no difference. Record does the same thing `type Record<K extends keyof any, T> = {[P in K]: T;};`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to use [const type parameter](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-5-0.html#const-type-parameters) to prevent the compiler from widening the type of the passed array to `string[]`.

Note that, *const type parameters* are available from the Typescript version `5.0`. For the prior versions the possible solution, but a bit annoying is to use [const assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) as it's done in @Behemoth's answer

```
function converArrayToObject<const T extends readonly string[]>(keys: T) {}
```

Now, we need to type the `reduce`, which should be an object where the keys are the elements of the array and the values are regular strings.

To get the type of elements we will need to use [indexed access](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html):

```
// 'aa' | 'bb'
type Case1 = ['aa', 'bb'][number]
```

Let's adapt it to the object that we need:

```
// type Case2 = {
//     aa: string;
//     bb: string;
// }
type Case2 = {[K in ['aa', 'bb'][number]]: string}
```

Looks good!

Let's assert the initial value of the reduce to this type:

```
function convertArrayToObject<const T extends readonly string[]>(keys: T) {
  return keys.reduce((prev, key) => ({ ...prev, [key]: key }), {} as {[K in T[number]]: string});
}
```

Testing:

```
// const result: {
//     aa: string;
//     bb: string;
// }
const result = convertArrayToObject(['aa', 'bb']);
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABBBA3ApgJygQU5gQwE8AVOAeQCMArdaAHhTAGcpETF0APKdMAE2aJM6AvwQAbIolaYYYAOYBtALoA+ABQBrdEWYAudgEpEAbwBQiYeighMSHXoB0I-iAjoNGgA4jUAGkRHEwBeNUQNU0QnGN90AMQlRxVDR0QAXyNA03TEAiFTJQBpRHl2JTAQAFtKLBUUmSg5RUyAbnN08y6mVmtmEAk2EOQ0LFx8YjIqWmgNJQByAgJ5wPnKSnmVI1agA)

Comment: why is `readonly` required?

Comment: @flyflydogdog check this [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABBBA3ApgJygQU5gQwE8AVOAeQCMArdaAHhTAGcpETF0APKdMAE2aJWmGGADmAbQC6APgAUAa3RFmALnYBKRAG8AUIkSZ0UEJiTLVAOmP8QEdPPkAHY6gA0iS9oC8sxPI6iFYhrugeiJKW0hqWiAC+mp468YgEQjqSANKIYuySYCAAtpRY0jHCUKISiQDcevF6TQD0zcgIrEbozCAANlAa+q2GI5JcGiJi4hWTEvXDjUydxj39iD7tYBjYeISkFDR0UPKSAOQEBKeep5SUp9Ka9XrDwAS9zOh6UETO6IgAwul0ABGdZdAj8BC9IiIQolLAyTg8PiCWHFUqYREAfkQVRAfw0r3en2GeM+31+AKBACYwXCMYjuLwBEJjBCoTD6QjpIgcWTEIS3h8gA). read-only arrays are not assignable to mutable arrays and `const` turns arrays to read-only version

Answer (score 2):

You can refactor `convertArrayToObject()` to accept a generic parameter which you can use to infer the return type. Unfortunately, you'll have to use [Type Assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) for the initial value of `.reduce()` to match the return type. Make sure to pass your argument array `as const` so the values can be inferred correctly and not just as `string`.

```
function convertArrayToObject<T extends readonly string[]>(
  keys: T
): {[K in T[number]]: string} {
  return keys.reduce(
    (prev, key) => ({...prev, [key]: key}),
    {} as {[K in T[number]]: string}
  );
}


const result = convertArrayToObject(["aa", "bb"] as const);
//    ^? const result: { aa: string; bb: string; }
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&jsx=0#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABBBA3ApgJygQU5gQwE8AVOAeQCMArdaAHhMXQA8p0wATAZ0U3QKcEAGyKJuUTDDABzANoBdAHwAKALAAoRIgDW6ItwBciEpoCUxgN5yA0omkm5YEAFtKWBQuMSpsgL6Ilpra-FAgmEh6BgB0-JwgEOjqWtqIKgAO-KgANLr6ZogAvEppltHlmeg5iHJRXnlEfmbZwamWAQS81nYOJE6u7pie3pLSMn6tZgDcmhMamihgEvZg6SBQRTUARAQEW7lblJRbCoidyAgSM-Mai8v83CDCG4UXYBjYeISkFDR0UCppGsoNNNAB6MGpRAAPQA-JpNEA)